# Не отображается BORDER

Tags: html, css, border

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>Bg clip</title>
    <style >
        .example{background:  url(image.jpg);
            background-clip: border-box;
            border: 20px blue !important;}
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <p class="example">ABCDEFG</p>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: Тип обводки забыл для бордера, например "solid".  border:  20px (толщина линии обводки) solid (сплошная линия) blue (цвет обводки);